# Python - Any way of checking if number 0 or False

Tags: python

If I were to set a variable as False, it is read as being equal to zero. Is there any way I can carry out a check to see if the variable if actually False or if it's the number 0.

Something like:

```
Spam = False

if Spam == False and not Spam == 0:
    do something
```

I'm getting the feeling this isn't possible; but I wanted to double check.

Side note: In the future would it be better to assign "None" rather than "False" when a variable could be zero? For the current code I don't want to have to rework the whole script with try and excepts, so I'll change False to -1 (not a viable value for the situation). But for future reference, I assume the None method is more Pythonic?

Help as always is appreciated and if any more details are needed, just ask.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Spam`, that it could take either a Boolean or an integer value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test if the object *is* the `False` singleton value, by testing for identity:

```
if Spam is False:
```

You should really refactor your code to not have to rely on the type here; `None` is a better false-y sentinel value to use, yes.

In general, use `None` as a sentinel meaning 'no value set', or if you should support `None` as well, use a unique object as a sentinel:

```
_sentinel = object()

# ...


if option is _sentinel:
    # no value set
```

Comment: Or even, if you feel like getting adventurous, `if not Spam`.

Comment: @killermonkey50 That's the opposite of what the OP is trying to do, which is distinguish between `False` and `0`.

Comment: @killermonkey50: No, because that'd be true for `0` too.

Comment: @killermonkey50: empty containers and numeric 0 are false in a boolean context, see [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Comment: This is brilliant. Will change the way I code in future, but this will save me having to completely rework the code (for now at least!).

Thank you very much for the help!